# Editing Exported Code - Construct 2

Tags: html, construct-2

A friend has asked me to check out an old uni project he did using Construct 2. It was made using a uni copy of Construct so I have no way of editing the original files, and only have access to the online export. Please bare in mind that I've never used Construct before, so I have no idea how it formats it's code. I'm more of a web designer but I said I'd have a go.

So the issue is it freezes after a few seconds. If I click quickly I can get past the intro screen, but if don't click the game freezes anyway. In other words the error is not caused by user input but by something happening in the background.

The example is here - http://rosietheband.com/moeba/

Has anyone seen this issue before? I was wondering if using an older browser might do the trick, as it worked a couple of years ago when it was made, and nothing else has changed since.

Answer (score 0):

It's a javascript error; I went poking around in Chrome's dev tools console and found this. The problem seems to be coming from the c2runtime.js and specifically the p.play function there, where it references A.Gain.Value (twice, near line 207). Removing all references to this seems to unbreak the game, though I don't know if it'll have any noticeable effects on the audio (since that's what the property seems to relate to.)

Look for these two references in c2runtime.js, both somewhere between lines 200-250

```
,this.A.gain.value=a*this.Lh
this.A.gain.value=c;
```

and remove them, and that appears to clear it up. (You might want to confirm that there aren't other references to 'A.gain' anywhere, in case this fix breaks them.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply jack! That was a real Doh! moment for me, completely neglected to check the console. I tried removing those lines, but now come up with the error "TypeError: this.A.noteOn is not a function". I'm not very experienced with JS/HTML5, and I get the feeling this wasn't particularly well designed in the first place. I think he was playing a number of audio files together on a loop, then using the "blobs" to unmute. Did you manage to get it working at your end?